# Android display rotation...save state

Tags: android, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am developing a web app with phonegap and jquery.
This scripts is composed by a javascript that create some form elements dinamically.

The problem is that when I change my screen orientation, the script run again from start.

How can I save the state?

Thanks.
Does exist a solution, or the only things is disable orientation screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your activity tag does not have the configChanges attribute set correctly in AndroidManifest.xml. It should look something like this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
```